# Can the natural numbers be defined in terms of the non-trivial zeta zeros?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Can the natural numbers be defined in terms of the non-trivial zeta zeros? Presumably they can, since $\pi(x)=\operatorname{R}(x)-\sum_{\rho}\operatorname{R}(x^\rho),$ and $\zeta(s)=\sum n^{-s}=\prod(1-p^{-s})^{-1} ,(s>1),$ but I have not come across it.

Comment: What do you mean by defined in terms of zeta zeros?

Comment: You need the primes a priori to define the product in question, so it's unclear what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer.

The trivial zeroes of the Riemann zeta function are $\{-2,-4,-6,...\}$. So the natural even numbers are the opposite of the trivial zeroes.

Edit: The OP changed *trivial* to *non trivial*.